# BST insertion not working using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a recursive way to insert to my binary search tree using java but it is not working properly gives null pointer exception 
my code for node.java is

```
public class Node
{
public int data;
public Node left;
public Node right;

public Node()
{
    this.data = -1;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}
public Node(int n)
{
    this.data = n;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
}
}
```

my code in Tree.java is

```
public class Tree
{
public Node head = new Node();

public void insert(int n , Node m)
{
    if(m == null || m.data == -1)
    {
        m = new Node(n);
    }
    else
    {
        if(m.data > n)
        {
            insert(n,m.left);
        }
        else if(m.data < n)
        {
            insert(n,m.right);
        }
    }
}
public void print()
{
    System.out.println(head.data);
    System.out.println(head.left.data);
    System.out.println(head.right.data);
}
}
```

and test.java code is

```
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Tree t = new Tree();
    Node m = new Node();
    t.insert(12,t.head);
    t.insert(11,t.head);
    t.insert(13,t.head);
    t.print();
}
}
```

when I compile and run, it gives following error

```
-1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Tree.print(Tree.java:28)
at Test.main(Test.java:10)
```

Comment: You never add children to your ``head`` node in your tree. Your insert method makes no sense

Comment: I am calling them recursively so in second or third steps m.left or m.right which are not nodes but I created them as in stack trace so I think there is o need of adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A few issues with the code as written:**

1. The base case (`if` block) of your insert doesn't actually modify the tree. It simply creates a new node and exits without linking the new node to the tree.
2. `t.head` starts with `data = -1`, so any subsequent call to `t.insert(..., t.head)` will hit the `if` block in `insert()` and do nothing, as mentioned in issue 1.
3. The NullPointerException doesn't happen until you try `t.print()` where you read `head.left.data`, but since you only have a single node tree at this point, `head.left` is null.

The core problem is your insert method doesn't add nodes properly. It needs to actually add the new node as a subtree of the current node.

**Here's the fixed code** (could probably be simplified):

```
public class Tree {
    public Node head = new Node();

    public void insert(int n , Node m)
    {
        if(m == head && head.data == -1) 
        {
            // if we have an empty tree, just change the head
            head.data = n;
        }
        else if(m.data > n) {
            // we should be adding to the left subtree here
            if(m.left == null) {
                // if no left subtree, create a new node and link to m's left
                m.left = new Node(n);
            }
            else {
                // otherwise call insert on left subtree recursively
                insert(n, m.left);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise add to right subtree
            if(m.right == null) {
                // no right subtree, so create node and link to m's right
                m.right = new Node(n);
            }
            else {
                // call recursively
                insert(n, m.right);
            }
        }
    }
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(head.data);
        System.out.println(head.left.data);
        System.out.println(head.right.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's the problem it is not going to else case, but I think in if m == -1 would be happened only for first case from second the value of m would be null as it is not a node itself( for further steps) ?